# How to use a value inside of an event handler. c#

Tags: c#, .net

Okay so I made a form and this is the code that doesn't seem to be working for me. I want to be able to use the int variable "guess" inside of the event handler for button1_click. I know there is probably some really easy answer for this, but I haven't been able to find it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int guess = rnd.Next(1, 100);
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(Form1.guess));
    }//It says that I can't use this value because it hasnt been created
//but if I create it, then it gives me a random number each time the button is clicked.
}
```

Comment: declare it at the form level not inside the constructor

Comment: Thank you. I should've known that.

Comment: yon should call the `Next` method any time you want to get a random number

Answer (score 3):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int Guess {get; set;} //<-----declare in a visible scope 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        guess = rnd.Next(1, 100); //<------this only happens once, make sure you change when and where needed. 
                                  //Which would mean that that your Random object should also be moved outside the Form1() Constructor.
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Guess.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Should not be `Form1.guess`, but instead `this.guess`. You're referencing a local variable of the same instance, not a static field.

Comment: You are correct. This was a copy and paste thing form his code. But the this. is still not required you can just use guess. I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Another option to you, if you don't want to promote `guess` to be a class-level field, is to use a lambda expression for the event handler like so:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int guess = rnd.Next(1, 100);
    button1.Click += (s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(guess));
    };
}
```

The variable `guess` is perfectly visible inside the lambda.